# Question about mathematical notation

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Should one really write `$\text{det}A$`, instead of `$detA$`, similarly `$\text{Aut}G$` instead of `$AutG$`, or is `$det$`, `$Aut$` acceptable?

Comment: I would use \operatorname{det}(A), as that's what it is.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 9):

Note that `$det(A)$` simply looks like it might mean `$d\cdot e\cdot t(A)$`. With respect to correct spacing in context, `\operatorname` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Better note that `\det` is predefined in LaTeX, so `$\det(A)$` will give the correct result out of the box.

Comment: @egreg Yes, `\operatorname` is rather for the generic case (such as `Aut` in the OP).

Answer (score 5):

1. `$\det A$`
2. `$\text{det}A$`
3. `$\mathrm{det}A$`
4. `$\operatorname{det}A$`

Personally, I prefer the first option or fourth option, as without italicization, it distinguishes the "operator" from the operand (matrix `$A$` in this case), and/or from other variables, which are italicized.

And the advantage of the first and last option is the slight increase in spacing between the operator `(\det) or (\operatorname{det}`) and the operand, $A$.

See Deven's suggestion in the comment below: if you plan to use the "operator" a lot in a given post, you can write a "preamble" defining a "new command", which helps economize the effort involved in formulating a long post.

Comment: You might also include an option using mathrm.

Comment: Just to point out to the OP, the last expression looks nice, but is quite tedious to write. I suggest putting something like "\newcommand{\det}{\operatorname{det}}" in your preamble if you will be using the operator often. Then you can call the code by simply writing \det

Comment: What is the difference between 2 and 3? My eyes can't really distinguish them..

Comment: I can't either, @Sanchez, but its appearance might depend on the browser's default text/font?

Comment: `\text` should generally not be used: it uses the font of the surrounding text, which might be italic or small caps... It should be reserved for words that *are part* of the text.

Comment: As for defining operators, there is a standard `\DeclareMathOperator` command in `amslatex.sty`.

Comment: `\operatorname` not only increases the spacing when it is needed, it also removed the space when the next thing is a delimiter (like parentheses) and has a couple of other technical niceties that make it *the* correct option.

Comment: There already is `\det`, no need to define it yourself.

Comment: The problem with the first option is not only italicization, but rather spacing. `$det A$` is equivalent to `$Atde$`, i.e. it is the product of variables `d`, `e`, `t` and `A`. Compare `$efg$` to `$\mathit{efg}$` (difference is more obvious).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I agree with you on the use of \DeclareMathOperator which has the advantage of getting superscripts and subscripts right.

Comment: For things that are operators `\DeclareMathOperator` or `\operatorname` is the way to go, for example `$\mathrm{sin}\theta$ just looks wrong. On the other hand, one might argue that things that are just names for sets, could just be written as `\mathrm{Mat}(R,n)` (obviously I'd make a `\Mat` macro), because it would not be used in a context where something could be seen as multiplication. `\text` should never be used to get something appear in upright, as it will be italic in an italic context.

Comment: The first one that is \det